# What are losses with binding all PDO params as PARAM_STR?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm creating a simple query builder for PHP PDO, to create queries faster, without doing lot of bind's and split query creating process to parts where conditions/orders/limits are composed together in dependency on some conditions (like filter engine, where you can select some criteria). I have method like this:

```
$query->addWhere( 'uid', '>' , 100 );
```

Which adds where condition and binds :uid to 100, i can also omitt bindig like this:

```
$query->addWhere( 'date', '>' , 'NOW()' , false );
```

But i don't bring information of 100 parameter type. Deeper in executing query, i don't do bindParam or bindValue, but passing my binded table to execute:

```
$stmt->execute( $query->getBinds() );
```

Do all of my parameters are treated as PARAM_STR or it gets PDO type from variable type in array ? What can I lose with that ? only performance/memory or there is possible some loss of data or logical error ?

P.S.
I don't want to create another classes for params, because I want keep it simple, I mean something like:

```
$query->addWhere( new Field('uid') , '=' , new IntParam( 100 ) ); or something
```

Comment: I hope you're sanitizing inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I see nothing good in such query builders (You gain as little as omitting few words and lose as many as making totally unreadable code out from precious SQL), the answer no: no loss.
Just turn emulating mode off, and PDO will detect necessary types automatically.

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

Comment: It's not matter of few words, it's matter of filter like (very simplified): if ( $_GET['cat'] ) add_category_condition; if ( $_GET['date'] ) add_date_condition; if ( $_GET['orderByPrice'] ) add_orderby_price; and finnaly $query->execute and display list of filtered (for example) products in shop. So user can mix up N conditions to see products from M >= N possible conditions to take (and same meaning for sorting list and paginating)

Comment: @killer I can stand custom where filters very well. But for the rest of the query I see no reason in making it this way. And I see no sense in having separate methods like add_orderby_price

Comment: @killer I'd rather make it `add_order($field,$arr_allowed,$direction)`

Comment: me too, I only simplified this. I just can't find simpler way to handle custom filtering + ordering + paginating. I don't wrote this solution for individual project but for inner-corporate framework where speed of creating modules with (lot of fields)CRUD+filter+order+pagination is most important.